# How can I add multiple values of duplicate keys to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have this list of dictionaries and I would like to make the port value the primary key since the port is the same in a lot of the dictionaries within the list.

Code:

```
def vrni_recommended_rules(json_output):
    response_dict = []
    ports = []
    source_ip = []
    for i in json_output['results']:
        ports.append(i['json']['port']['display'])
        response_dict.append(dict(
            source_ip = i['json']['source_ip']['ip_address'],
            destination_ip = i['json']['destination_ip']['ip_address'],
            protcol = i['json']['protocol'].lower(),
            traffic_type = i['json']['traffic_type'].lower(),
            iana_name = i['json']['port']['iana_name'],
            port = i['json']['port']['display'],
            firewall_action = i['json']['firewall_action'].lower(),
            protocol_number = i['json']['protocol'].replace('UDP', '17').replace('TCP', '6')
            ))


    return response_dict
```

I get the following response:

```
"results": [
        {
            "destination_ip": "199.7.7.7",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "15.225.50.14",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "96.6.6.6",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "192.155.2.199",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "dns",
            "port": "53",
            "protcol": "udp",
            "protocol_number": "17",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "30.22.239.107",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "55.55.55.55",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "66.66.66.66",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "192.192.192.125",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "ldaps",
            "port": "636",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "192.192.192.192",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "ntp",
            "port": "123",
            "protcol": "udp",
            "protocol_number": "17",
            "source_ip": "192.30.0.1",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        },
        {
            "destination_ip": "99.99.99.99",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": "192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I zip the dictionary with ports as the primary key, it obviously removes the duplicates.

If I add:

```
    d = dict(zip(ports, response_dict))

    return d
```

I get:

```
    "results": {
        "123": {
            "destination_ip": 192.30.30.30",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "ntp",
            "port": "123",
            "protcol": "udp",
            "protocol_number": "17",
            "source_ip": 192.30.0.1",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        },
        "443": {
            "destination_ip": "52.52.52.52",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": 192.30.6.250",
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
        },
        "53": {
            "destination_ip": 192.2.2.2",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "dns",
            "port": "53",
            "protcol": "udp",
            "protocol_number": "17",
            "source_ip": 192.30.6.2",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        },
        "636": {
            "destination_ip": 192.30.30.30",
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "ldaps",
            "port": "636",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": 192.30.6.6",
            "traffic_type": "east_west_traffic"
        }
    }
}
```

It's almost how I want it, however I want to make sure that if there are more than one dictionary with port 443 or some other port, that it would show up under the primary port key...

How I want it...

```
        "443": {
            "destination_ip": ["52.52.52.52", "53.53.53.53", "54.54.54.54"],
            "firewall_action": "allow",
            "iana_name": "https",
            "port": "443",
            "protcol": "tcp",
            "protocol_number": "6",
            "source_ip": ["192.30.6.250", "192.168.30.30", "192.6.6.6"],
            "traffic_type": "internet_traffic"
            }
```

Comment: I think you are heading for trouble. Example, if you have rules for port 53 (dns), you will probably have rules for both udp and tcp. Maybe one is allowed, the other dropped. I think you should rethink the final dict format ("how I want it") to make sure it is appropriate.

Comment: That is a fair concern!

Answer (score 1):

for the output you expect I think you can do something like this:

```py
def vrni_recommended_rules(json_output):
    response_dict = {}
    for i in json_output["results"]:
        port = i["json"]["port"]["display"]
        try:
            port_dict = response_dict[port]
        except KeyError:
            response_dict[port] = dict(
                source_ip=[i["json"]["source_ip"]["ip_address"]],
                destination_ip=[i["json"]["destination_ip"]["ip_address"]],
                protcol=i["json"]["protocol"].lower(),
                traffic_type=i["json"]["traffic_type"].lower(),
                iana_name=i["json"]["port"]["iana_name"],
                port=i["json"]["port"]["display"],
                firewall_action=i["json"]["firewall_action"].lower(),
                protocol_number=i["json"]["protocol"].replace("UDP", "17").replace("TCP", "6"),
            )
        else:
            port_dict["destination_ip"].append(i["json"]["destination_ip"]["ip_address"])
            port_dict["source_ip"].append(i["json"]["source_ip"]["ip_address"])

    return response_dict
```

By the way I can't run it because you didn't provide the .json so I didn't test this code.

Comment: This works the way I want it, I just need to address two concerns. One mentioned by @vaizki and one with source IP. since source IP is the same a lot of times, I end up getting duplicates in the list, but I think I can handle that later in the code.

Comment: I see. To fix the repetitivity of source IP you could simply replace the list structure by a set and so the append method with the add one. This way source IP will automatically get rid of duplicated IPs. To address the issue mentionned by @vaizki you could gather the protocol and it’s rules into a nested dict with protocols as keys and the related rule as value. If the rule associated to a given protocol could concern more than just the firewall action, the value could be another data structure of your choice. I can give you an implementation of it if it’s unclear.